# Testing if the Editfield is editable using LeanFt

Tags: java, gui-testing, leanft

We have an editfield or textbox that is detected as a Winforms editfield in the object identification center of LeanFt, when it is spied upon. Whether it is editable or not depends on some pre-conditions. Depending on the pre-conditions we recreate, We would like to test if the editfield is editable or not. We would like to do something like

```
Assert.assertEquals(false, txtEditfield.isEditable());
```

However I could not find a isEditable method in the [SDK](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/JavaSDKReference/com/hp/lft/sdk/winforms/EditField.html).

Comment: How do you define *is editable*? Is enabled? We must answer this question first

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct. There is no `isEditable()` method for winforms editfield. The field gets enabled for certain selection present in the form. Try using `isEnabled()`

Like:

`Assert.assertEquals(false, txtEditfield.isEnabled());`